# Update multiple tables with join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I can't handle the update statement, based on several tables. I've already viewed tutorials and forums, customized my code, tried, tried... But still doesn't work.

Code:

```
UPDATE `system` 
                JOIN System AS Sys ON service.Servicename_ID = Sys.FK_Service_ID 
                JOIN Hardware ON System.System_ID = Hardware.FK_System_ID
                JOIN Verantwortlichkeit ON System.System_ID = Verantwortlichkeit.FK_System_ID
                JOIN Zertifikate ON System.System_ID = Zertifikate.FK_System_ID
                JOIN hardware_servername ON hardware.Servername = hardware_servername.Servername_ID
                JOIN hardware_domaene ON hardware_domaene.Domaene_ID = hardware.Domaene
                JOIN hardware_betriebssystem ON hardware_betriebssystem.Betriebssystem_ID =             hardware.Betriebssystem
                JOIN hardware_standort ON hardware_standort.Standort_ID = hardware.Standort
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS AA ON AA.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = system.Hersteller
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS AB ON AB.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = system.Externer_Partner
                JOIN system_verfuegbarkeitsstufe ON system_verfuegbarkeitsstufe.Verfuegbarkeitsstufe_ID = system.Verfuegbarkeitsstufe
                JOIN system_systemname ON system_systemname.Systemname_ID = system.Systemname
                JOIN system_systemnummer ON system_systemnummer.Systemnummer_ID = system.Systemnummer
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_rolle ON verantwortlichkeit_rolle.Verantwortlichkeit_Rolle_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Rolle
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A0 ON A0.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Hauptverantwortlicher
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A1 ON A1.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Stellvertretung
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A2 ON A2.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Wissenstraeger_1
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A3 ON A3.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Wissenstraeger_2
                JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A4 ON A4.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Verantwortlichkeit_extern
                SET 
                Sys.Systemnummer = '1', 
                Sys.Systembeschreibung = 'testbeschreubuzng', 
                Sys.Hersteller = 'Okan Koc', 
                Sys.Externer_Partner = 'Okan Koc', 
                Sys.`BKAG_Brugg` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BCIAG_Brugg` = b'1', 
                Sys.`Cables_Diverse_PL_CN_US_DE` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BINF` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BRAG_Kleindoettingen` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BRG_Wunstorf` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BGP_Nordhausen` = b'1', 
                Sys.`Pipes_Diverse_FR_PL_IT_US` = b'1', 
                Sys.`Ropes_BDAG_Birr` = b'1', 
                Sys.`HOLDING_Brugg` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BIAG_Brugg` = b'1', 
                Sys.`BPK_Brugg` = b'1', 
                Sys.`Dritte_Schule_Brugg_LithCom_usw` = b'1', 
                Sys.`Verfuegbarkeitsstufe` = '1', 
                Sys.`Datenverlust` = '1', 
                Sys.`Systemname` = 'Testsystem', 
                hardware.`Servername` = 'srvntstest',
                hardware.`Domaene` = 'cables.bruggnet.com',
                hardware.`Betriebssystem` = 'Windows Server 2012 R2',
                hardware.`Lokale_Datenbank` = '1',
                hardware.`Datenbank_SQL_Master` = 'SQLTEST',
                hardware.`Instanzname` = 'Testinstanz',
                hardware.`Standort` = 'RZ 1',
                hardware.`Backup_mit` = 'Veeam',

                verantwortlichkeit.`Rolle` = 'Systemtechnik',
                verantwortlichkeit.`Hauptverantwortlicher` = 'David Grunder',
                verantwortlichkeit.`Stellvertretung` = 'Robin Gloor',
                verantwortlichkeit.`Wissenstraeger_1` = 'Okan Koc',
                verantwortlichkeit.`Wissenstraeger_2` = 'Marc Gerber',
                verantwortlichkeit.`Verantwortlichkeit_extern` = 'infor',
                zertifikate.`Zertifikatname` = 'testzertifikat',
                zertifikate.`Ablaufdatum` = '27.12.2001'

                WHERE Sys.System_ID = 1
```

Comment: In what sense doesn't work?

Comment: @P.Salmon
Hi Salomon, first of all thank you for the reason that you reserved your time to give an answer... I forgot to write what the error is; the error which is coming up in mysql is like following: "#1054 - Unknown tablefield 'service.Servicename_ID' in on clause." the problem is i have such a field and i can execute other querys (so the relations work), but something do not want here in this update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to spot all possible errors in such a long query but the second line contains two errors as I see it, `Service` is not defined and you're joining with the `System` table itself

```
UPDATE `system` 
  JOIN System AS Sys ON service.Servicename_ID = Sys.FK_Service_ID
```

It needs to be changed to something like

```
UPDATE System Sys
  JOIN Service ON Service.Servicename_ID = Sys.FK_Service_ID
```

Comment: oh yeah i try it and this error is coming no more.. thanks

Comment: i have another problem too..
I have 4 main tables, and they each have about 5-6 sub-tables by linking the data with PK/FK keys.
Now I have an "edit view" on my php surface, here come the different entries and I can select new datasets by dropdown. I now want to enter the current or edited status in my database using this update command. The thing is, I have the feeling that I can't technically implement this, because I just connected the main tables with sub-tables via the IDs. do you have an idea or have you even experienced this problem?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: I'm not experienced with "edit view" and php surface so I suggest you post a new question for this.